# How to store ZIP files in MongoDB using gridfs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs

want to store ZIP files in my MongoDB database, they are more than 16 MB
I try to use mongoose-gridfs but couldn't get the file back

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/cache').then(() => {
  const { model: Attachment } = gridfs({
    collection: 'attachments',
    model: 'Attachment',
    mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection
  });

  const readStream = fs.createReadStream('./test.zip');
  const options = ({ filename: 'cache.zip', contentType: 'application/zip' });

  Attachment.write(options, readStream, (error, file) => console.log(error,file) );
});
```

it returns an object id for example - 5cc2d68d9572233b3004952a
but then I try to get that file

```
  Attachment.readById('5cc2d68d9572233b3004952a', (err, buffer ) => console.log(buffer));
```

I got Undefined

In my MongoDB (Screens)
 [attachment chunks](http://prntscr.com/nh59i4)
 [attachemnt files](http://prntscr.com/nh5a8d)